# Fancybox looping through multiple albums

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, gallery

I found this question unanswered in Google Groups and I'm facing the same bug in **Fancybox**.

I have more image galleries on one page. When I go to the next image
with the next prev buttons, and so on, I'll get to the images from the
other gallery.

With lightbox it's possible to do something like:

```
<a href="url" rel="fancybox[gallery1]" >link</a>
```

and I'll get all the images from
gallery1 in an image gallery. My albums are dynamic so I can't do it
in my javascript file.

Is this possible?

How would we control this navigation?

```
<div class="Album" />
<div class="AlbumImg">
   <a class="big_img" title="Tokyo" rel="flickr_group" href="tokyo.jpg"></a>
   <div id="Gallery0">
      <a class="big_img" title="Tokyo rel="flickr_group" href=""Tokyobig></a>
      <a class="grouped_elements" title="Tokyo" rel="Gallery0" href="Tokyo1"></a>
   </div>
  <div id="Gallery0">
     <a class="grouped_elements" title="Tokyo" rel="Gallery0" href="Tokyo2"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="Gallery0">
      <a class="grouped_elements" title="Tokyo" rel="Gallery0" href="Tokyo3.jpg"></a>
   </div>
   <img class="first" src="Tokyo" title="Tokyo" />
   </a>
</div>

<div class="AlbumImg">
   <a class="big_img" title="Tokyo" rel="flickr_group" href="tokyo.jpg"></a>
   <div id="Gallery1">
      <a class="big_img" title="Tokyo rel="flickr_group" href=""Tokyobig></a>
      <a class="grouped_elements" title="Tokyo" rel="Gallery1" href="Tokyo1"></a>
   </div>
  <div id="Gallery1">
     <a class="grouped_elements" title="Tokyo" rel="Gallery1" href="Tokyo2"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="Gallery1">
      <a class="grouped_elements" title="Tokyo" rel="Gallery1" href="Tokyo3.jpg"></a>
   </div>
   <img class="first" src="Tokyo" title="Tokyo" />
   </a>
</div>
```

This is the code I have where every album holds a number of images. When i hit the last image of the first album and navigate next I get to the first pic of the second album. But I want to cycle back to the first image of the same abum

Comment: Could you add the `HTML` from your page with the different galleries?

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted contains a lot of errors...

You have multiple `div`'s with the same `id`, and the attributes aren't contained within the quotes, in both `<div class="AlbumImg">` there are a unmatched closing tag `</a>`. I'm not so sure that any of this matters for your example but you should definitely look in to it. And as Ruben said **fancybox** should work with the `rel` attribute as well, just like lightbox.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<div class="albums">
    <div class="gallery1">
        <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150.png" rel="gallery1">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150.png"/>
        </a>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150.png" rel="gallery1">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150.png"/>
        </a>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150.png" rel="gallery1">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150.png"/>
        </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="gallery2">
        <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150.png" rel="gallery2">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150.png"/>
        </a>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150.png" rel="gallery2">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150.png"/>
        </a>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150.png" rel="gallery2">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150.png"/>
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you want your galleries to cycle you have to pass a parameter to **fancybox**. See the [documentation](http://fancybox.net/api). Should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').fancybox({
            'cyclic':true
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery-x" href="Tokyo3.jpg">
```

this should work? don't forget the '-'
if it doenst work, can you provide the jquery code?